# Trying to identify the names of ikea hardware

Tags: hardware

This piece is #124401 they sent me 1, I need 2 and feel it would be faster to just go out and get one myself but I can’t find the name. Any thoughts?[image]

Comment: IKEA does not  use words,  names are words, They only  have crudely drawn illustrations, and part numbers.  Fun aside, **we do not even know what this part is intended to do nor what unit it goes to**.

Comment: Did you find this item eventually? I am looking for exactly the same now, curious if they helped you at Ikea. I've lost this cross brace during moving...

Answer (score 6):

It's part of an IKEA TYSSEDAL Bed frame.
Part number 124401
[Assembly Instructions](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/tyssedal-bed-frame__AA-1289653-5_pub.pdf)

Ikea will be the only place to find a part like this.

[According to Ikea](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/customer-service/returns-claims/troubleshooting/):

> Sometimes things don't go as planned. If your order arrived incomplete, contained damaged products, or didn't even show up, we're here to help.
>
> - Visit your closest store
> - [Email us](https://www.ikea.com/ext/us/contact-us/#!/)
> - Give us a call 1-888-888-4532

They should be able to help you if you tell them "Tyssedal bed frame part number 124401"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This part # 124401 is a cross brace. You can just search in google as “124401 IKEA” and you may find some for sale.